# Factorise $ax^2-16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What does this question mean?

Use the difference between two squares to factorise $ax^2-16$.

Comment: I think you really have to get a basic high school algebra book and read about this stuff there and, *above all*, practice a lot!

Comment: @user61521: Did you look at the other examples and try to solve these? It will not be helpful if we provide answers, but you don't try. Regards

Comment: sorry I'm only 12.... ok well what are two pair of numbers product is -9 and sum 8

Comment: I am trying, it's just I have a big book of year 11 stuff I have to do and it's hard

Comment: I got it now it's (x - 8) (x - 1) right????????

Comment: well would someone at least answer the question that i edited? I get the factorising now.

Comment: Did you mean $\, (ax)^2 - 16\,$? $\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

(1) In general, $\,a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)\,$ . In $\,x^2-16\,$ , what is $\,a\,$ and what $\,b\,$?

(2) If there are two numbers $\,\alpha\,,\,\beta\,$ s.t. $\,\alpha\beta= c\,\,,\,\,\alpha+\beta=-b\,$ , then

$$x^2+bx+c=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$

Find these two pairs of numbers for $\,x^2-9x+8\;\,\;\;x^2-18x+81\,$

**Note:** Above, we do **not** require $\,\alpha\neq \beta\,$ ...!